# Get Value from HTML table and use it for edit a record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hey there I am new to HTML and PHP for time I have successfully done what i want to achieve but there is one thing that is going wrong: the case is:
Remember that this is not an assignment but I'm trying to do it for learning!

I have a mytable.php file where i have to show the records into table fetched from the mysql db

then i have an edit button so that i can edit my details

pressing edit button i go to edit.php and there i have to edit the record data in mysqli query where some condition should come from mytable.php
my code is:

\mytable.php//

```
session_start();
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Q4Part a</title>
</head>

<body>


    //and for mysqli_connection string will be
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db');
            if($con){
                $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users");
                    if($result){
                        echo "<table>";

                        echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>";
                                echo "Username";
                            echo "</td>";

                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "Password";
                                echo "</td>";

                                    /*echo "<td>";
                                        echo "Pass";
                                    echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo "Phone";
                                        echo "</td>";

                                            echo "<td>";
                                                echo "Address";
                                            echo "</td>";

                                                echo "<td>";
                                                    echo "Action";
                                                echo "</td>";   */
                        echo "</tr>";
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>";
                                        echo $row['myusername'];
                                    echo "</td>";

                                        echo "<td>";
                                            echo $row['mypassword'];
                                        echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>";
                                                            echo "<a href='edit.php'>edit</a>";

                                                            $_SESSION['username']=$row['myusername'];
                                                            //to go to the edit.php
                                                        echo "</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        echo "</table>";
                    }else{
                        echo mysqli_error($con);
                        //so that if query won't run!
                    }
            }
            else{
                echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
                //or you can use exit that shows an error message and terminates the current script
                //and or die which is a substitue for exit function and also shows the error message and terminates the current script
                //so
                exit("Connection error!");
                    //we can also use die(string);
                die("Connection error");
            }

</body>
</html>
```

\edit.php//

```
    session_start();
    $username=$_SESSION['username'];
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit File</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','db');
            if($con){
                $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where myusername='".$username."'");
                //where $username contains the current user that has been already signed in in the current time!//
                    if($result){
                        echo "<form action='save_edit.php' method='post'>";
                        echo "<table>";
                            echo "<th colspan='5'>";
                                echo "edit your details!";
                            echo "</th>";

                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<input type='text' name='username' value='".$row['myusername']."'>";
                                echo "</td>";

                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<input type='text' name='email' value='".$row['mypassword']."'>";
                                echo "</td>";



                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<button type='submit'>Edit Changes</button>";
                                echo "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";

                        echo "</form>";

                    }else{
                        echo mysqli_error($con);
                    }
            }
            else{
                echo mysqli_connect_error($con);    
            }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

all is working fine and good but it only gets the last result always when i click on the link 'edit'

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead of mysqli_fetch_array(). You're using a hashmap (associative array) so make sure you access it accordingly. Try doing `var_dump($row);` after your while statement to get an object print out of the array.

Lastly, you should never store passwords in plain text in the database. The password should be stored hashed, so you never have the ability to view the password again. When the user logs in, you check if the pass is valid by rehashing it and comparing for a match. Eg: $pass = `md5($_POST['password'])`

You should also consider using HTML5. Your doctype makes you use HTML4 and there's not many good reasons to do that anymore. I'd recommend changing to  which sets it to HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['username']` will store the very last username you retrieved from the database/displayed on the page, so that's not going to work.

The standard way to do this is to use a unique identifier for each row in the database, and pass that as a URL parameter to edit.php.

If the username is always unique you can do something like this.

in mytable.php:

```
//echo "<a href='edit.php'>edit</a>";
echo "<a href='edit.php?username=" . urlencode($row['myusername']) . "'>edit</a>";
//$_SESSION['username']=$row['myusername'];
```

in edit.php:

```
//$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

Comment: i must use the session variables

Comment: Unless this is some kind of assignment I don't see why.

Comment: it is not an assignment and secondly i am doing it for my own learning if you dont want to help then its ok take your time :)

Comment: It's not going to work.  If you display 20 users each with an Edit button, your php code can only know which one was clicked on by some kind of HTTP request with a parameter set.  You could do `$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['username']`, and then `$username = $_SESSION['username']`, but that is pointless.